# Turn flash radio player code to html radio player code

Tags: flash, html5-audio

I have some very old code from [www.muses.org/setup](http://www.muses.org/setup) where I created a radio player. I am trying to host the skin files on my server but it forces me to use flash which is no longer supported.

This is the code for the widget it gives me:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="189" height="61">
<param name="movie" value="muses.swf" />
<param name="flashvars" value="url=https://rheath1.radioca.st/;&lang=en&codec=mp3&volume=75&introurl=&autoplay=true&tracking=true&jsevents=true&buffering=3&skin=ffmp3-testskin.xml&title=Kidz%20Corner Radio" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="scale" value="noscale" />
<embed src="muses.swf" flashvars="url=https://rheath1.radioca.st/;&lang=en&codec=mp3&volume=75&introurl=&autoplay=true&tracking=true&jsevents=true&buffering=3&skin=ffmp3-testskin.xml&title=Kidz%20Corner Radio" width="189" scale="noscale" height="61" wmode="transparent" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
</object>
```

Would anyone have any idea how to make this code work for html5 so it's supported? I have the files on my webserver already but it's a matter of making a responsive player via html instead of flash and still picking up where the player skin files are on my server.

Any ideas would be very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: _"I am trying to host the skin files on my server"_ Try using the HTML5 embed code but change path of JS file (`mrp.js`) to point to the copy on your server and also set skin as `'skin':'https://www.yourserver.com/yourskin.xml',`...

Comment: OK I tried it but the player isn't visible                                                                                                   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kidzcornerradio.com/muses/mrp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
MRP.insert({
'url':'https://rheath1.radioca.st/;',
'lang':'en',
'codec':'mp3',
'volume':75,
'autoplay':true,
'forceHTML5':true,
'jsevents':true,
'buffering':0,
'title':'Kidz Corner Radio',
'wmode':'transparent',
'skin':'https://www.kidzcornerradio.com/muses/testSkin.xml',
'width':189,
'height':61
});
</script>

Comment: Something is wrong with how it sees your custom XML skin. You can see the player only if you change skin path setting to their own skin like...  `'skin' : 'mcclean',` but why won't it accept your own XML??? I'll investigate when I get a chance. PS: For sound to work I had set URL as `https://rheath1.radioca.st/;`

Comment: Thank you so much! Here's the page where the player is: https://kidzcornerradio.com/muses.html (I right clicked and hit "View Source" to see the code)

Comment: OK I think the problem might be a silly little technical issue... I notice your URL/paths start with `https://kidzcornerradio.com/` but for the skin part that XML has `https://www.kidzcornerradio.com/` which somehow makes the browser think it's mixing two different servers (you cannot load an XML from another site with Javascript). **Possible solution**: Remove the `www.` in the **skin** path and test again. Hope it works!! **PS** Most sites have `www` in their name anyway so normally it should have worked at first try.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I removed the www but still no luck. I wonder why because I can see the correct code in view source but can't hear or see the player.

Comment: Check back in 10 minutes. I'll test your code on my local server and let you know if/how it can be adjusted to work.

Comment: Late report... So I made some progress. After some minor edits, [this is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTYsr.png) if I host your HTML, your XML and related images all on my server. What's your browser  and can you get to its **Developer Tools**? Check the **console** tab. I suspect you either have CORS issue or you got `404 Error` which is "file not found".

Comment: PS: On your site: https://kidzcornerradio.com/muses.html the player seems to be working now. Did you already fix it (or is my laptop glitching)? Anyways at bottom part of that page code, change the `width` to **250** and the `height` to **78** to match your BackGround picture dimensions (_example:_ `'width':250,`).

Comment: OMG thank you! It is working now! You are the best and I thank you so much for figuring it out! I put it on the homepage as well! www.kidzcornerradio.com

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:

- Copy the [Muses Radio Player JS file](https://hosted.muses.org/mrp.js) to your server.
- Create an XML file and edit it with your server's image paths (URL).

For testing, paste this code below into a blank page, save as `index.html` then test the file in browser. Also put the `.html`, the `.xml` and images together in one place (*eg:* same folder).

This is an example of the final working code:

```
<!-- BEGINS: AUTO-GENERATED MUSES RADIO PLAYER CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://hosted.muses.org/mrp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
MRP.insert({
'url':'https://mystreamlink/;',
'lang':'en',
'codec':'mp3',
'volume':100,
'autoplay':false,
'jsevents':true,
'buffering':0,
'title':'My-Radio-Name',
'skin':'https://mywebsite.com/testSkin.xml',
'width':180,
'height':60
});
</script>
<!-- ENDS: AUTO-GENERATED MUSES RADIO PLAYER CODE -->
```

**note:**

- The `'url'` should end with `/;` (so add it, if needed).
- The shown `'width':180, 'height':60` settings must be changed. 
  (to match your XML's `<bg>` image size).

The `testSkin.xml` file looks like this: 
(an XML is just a text file, so you create it same like an HTML or TXT)

```
<muses-skin folder="test-skins-images" togglePlayStop="false">
  <bg image="bg.jpg" x="0" y="0" ></bg>
  <play image="play.jpg" x="10" y="10" clickimage="playclick.jpg" />
  <stop image="stop.jpg" x="50" y="10" clickimage="stopclick.jpg" />
  <text x="15" y="49" width="170" height="22" color="#ffffff" font="Arial" size="16" align="left" />
  <songtitle x="12" y="83" width="210" height="22" color="#000000" font="Arial" size="12" />
  <artist x="12" y="103" width="210" height="22" color="#000000" font="Arial" size="12" />
  <volume x="92" y="14" width="100" height="22" 
      colOr1="#ffffff" color2="#ff0000"
      barwidth="3"
      barStep="5"
      holderImage="holder.jpg"
      mode="holder"  You-can-try-with-mode="bars or vholder"
  />
  <status imagePlay="statusplay.jpg" imageStop="statusstop.jpg" x="2" y="2" />
</muses-skin>
```

Finally make sure the following images exist:

`bg.jpg`, `play.jpg`, `playclick.jpg`, `stop.jpg`, `stopclick.jpg`, 
`holder.jpg`, `statusplay.jpg` and `statusstop.jpg`.